# How to find file creation time in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, datetime, time, unix-timestamp

I have tried a lot of google search to find out file creation time in linux but not luck.

Is there any way to find actual file creation time in Linux ?

Answer (score 1):

Linux offers three timestamps for files: time of last access of contents (atime), time of last modification of contents (mtime), and time of last modification of the inode (metadata, ctime). So, no, you cannot. The directory's mtime corresponds to the last file creation or deletion that happened, though.